# Php redirect causing 302 for ajax redirect

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my core script of login controller this means all the sanitization and verification of user is done.

code inside LoginController.php

```
if ( password_verify($valid['pass'], $pass) ) {
    // My session stuffs

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode (array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'Login successful..! You will be redirected in a moment'
    ));
    redirect('user/profile'); //Ajax redirect only works when I remove this.
    exit;
}
```

Code inside login.php

```
try {
    LoginController::UserLogin(); // Calling my method inside my controller
} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo json_encode(array(
        'error' => array(
            'msg' => $e->getMessage()
        ),
    ), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit;

}


<form id="login_form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME)); ?>" class="form" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="login_username" placeholder="Enter username" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="login_pass" placeholder="Enter password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="login_security" placeholder="Enter Security 25 * 2" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-green" id="login-btn">Login</button>

</form>
```

My ajax part

```
$('#login_form #login-btn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url : $('#login_form').attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.error) {
                $('.error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + data.error.msg + '</div>');
            }
            if ( data.result === 'success' ) {
                $('.error').html('<div class="alert alert-unknown">' + data.msg + '</div>');
                setTimeout('window.location.href = "user/profile.php";',3000);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My problem: Everything works fine until I use ajax. This means the page without Ajax shows error and everything is fine. But when I use ajax the errors are returned but when the login details are correct (Valid details) the page gets stuck(The page is not redirected).

When I check the developer console what I see is this 302 for login page and the redirect is not taking place(But it works when I remove the header from the Login controller form this causes no redirect when the user does not have JavaScript disabled).

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `302`, not `304`? If so, that's a perfectly valid response

Comment: Oops it is a 302 error. And the issue is the page is not redirected with ajax.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Also, remember to send all headers before the first non-header content

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works:

In the LoginController.php: REMOVE the `redirect` after the `echo` part.

In the Login.php, put the `header` BEFORE the `echo` part.

In the Ajax part, chage the `success` part like this:

```
success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.error) {
            $('.error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + data.error.msg + '</div>');
        }
        if ( data.result === 'success' ) {
            $('.error').html('<div class="alert alert-unknown">' + data.msg + '</div>');
            // -> here
            // correct setTimeout function
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location = "user/profile.php";
            },3000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now the ajax part is working properly but the raw json is printed when the JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: Yes, Ajax and Jquery can't work without JavaScript. If you want your page to work without JS as well, you have to make a change like this: send a parameter like "ajax=0" if the form is sent without js, and "ajax=1" if js is working. In the php file you check the "ajax" parameter and decide what to do. (send Json or redirect directly)

Answer (score 0):

there must be a redirect set at the start of your controller , if ur using the FuelPhp please check for a function called "before", then include your exception function inside

```
public function before()
{
    parent::before();

    $login_exception = array("login");

    parent::check_permission($login_exception);
}
```